# can I fit a GMM over probability distributions?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

We have been using a GMM to fit gaussians over a set of ~ 3M vectors.

Now the input are not vectors but **probability distributions** (coming from a topic model like LDA). Is it still mathematically sound to fit/train a GMM over such input?

Comment: What do you mean by probability distributions? How are you representing it in the code without vectors?